# Create a Geotiff file from scattered data in python

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, geotiff

I have a dataset of points (latitude, longitude, value) and i want to create a Geotiff file from these points.

latitude,longitude and the value are float32 numbers

I want to generate a custom raster that interpolate over those points.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180712070529/http://www.gdal.org:80/grid_tutorial.html)

I want to obtain a grid as in the link above and for every point in the grid have a value (computed from original points with some kind of interpolation i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you pointed in your question is the theory behind gdal_grid utility:

https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html

Check the bottom of the page for examples of how to interpolate a geotiff from scattered data.

For how to use in python:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254330/python-gdal-grid-correct-use